# Yii Framework: AJAX Call from JQuery return average from MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hey everyone I'm attempting to take the value inputed in one of my forms, a country name, and query my database table for rows that have the corresponding country in the country column. I would then like to take those rows, and average together the values for a certain column, std_rate, of those rows. hen take that value and dynamically update anothe field in my form called PackagingMetric_std_rate. This is what I have so far, but I cannot get it to work. I've tried several different methods, but nothing seems to work!

This is my jquery statement...

```
$('#country').bind('change',function() 
{
  var input_country = $('#country').val();

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: input_country,
  url: 'country_rate.php',

  success: function(data) {

  $('#PackagingMetric_std_rate').html(data);
    }

});


});
```

It should be calling this file, 'country_rate.php' which is contained in the same directory as the form calling this file with Ajax.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$password = "password"; 

$database = "myDatabase";

$country = $POST['input_country'];

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName,$connection);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(std_rate)FROM packaging_metrics WHERE country like `$country` ");
$std_rate = mysql_fetch_row($query); 

$std_rate = json_encode($std_rate);
```

I am getting no change when country is changed in my form. No error, or anything. Is there something wrong with my setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, you should be using `GET` not `POST` here since you're not modifying any data. You also need to escape the value of `$country` (e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string($country)`). As far as the problem you're experiencing, have you tried running the queries manually to see if you get what you expect?

Comment: I just tried changing $country to a string of a country that I know exists. However, I keep getting the value null echo'd onto the page, alongside the error Warning: mysql_feth_row() expects parameter 1 to be a resource, boolean given in ...

Comment: I was able to rectify this by removing the portion of the query after "FROM packaging_metircs", so this returns a value from what I assume is an average of the column for every single row in the database. I think the issue comes from how my query is written.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the generated query and executed manually? If you're seeing the error you described, you probably want to look at the output of `mysql_error()` as there's probably an error in your query. (At minimum, it appears you're not correctly quoting the country.)

Comment: I have solved the query issue, after fiddling around I am finally getting the result echoed on a screen after manually querying it. I still however am having the same issue regarding the AJAX call not working –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is generating error because of `` quotes you are using for $country. Using single qoutes ' resolves it for me.

Comment: I have solved the query issue, after fiddling around I am finally getting the result echoed on a screen after manually querying it. I still however am having the same issue regarding the AJAX call not working